# where does paperclip store relationship between an interpolator using a hash and the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I am using paperclip and would like to process a set of files offline and ideally move them to a content server. But I am not seeing where paperclip is storing this information to be able to get at it. The hash used isn't meant to obfuscate so I'm not that worried about it but would like to handle different images with same name as we've had problems with this from current digital cameras.

I have the following interpolation:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :val  do |attachment, style|
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest("me-" + attachment.size.to_s + "-other")
end

has_attached_file :asset, 
  :url => "/images/:global_path/:val-:style.:extension",
  :path => UPLOAD_PATH + "/:global_path/:val-:style.:extension",
  :styles => { :medium => "200x200>", :thumb => "75x75>", :bigthumb => "125x125"  

  }
```

Producing a url like: /images/170/1c8ce44646e4cbe816ebe901482783e9-thumb.jpg?1337831837

I'd like to be able to rsync the images directory but can't find how to get at the hash value. Where would I find this?

thx

Comment: I havent used paperclip much, so excuse me if this is a silly question, but paperclip provides obfuscation of image urls https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#uri-obfuscation, why are you using custom interpolation?

Comment: thx - I started using their obfuscation pattern but it obfuscates each one differently (if you have 1 image with 4 different styles, you get 4 different hashes). I want each to have the same hash.